# two dictionaries from text file where values are columns and key line counts

Tags: python, dictionary

My file has this pattern (this is an example). I want to create two dictionaries with each column as values, and key as integers.

```
John  Moor
Age   22
id    112
grade 60

Amy  Ling
Age  22
id   114
grade 67
```

The dictionaries should look like this:

```
dict1 = {1 : ["John", "Age", "id", "grade"], 2 : ["Amy", "Age", "id", "grade"]}
dict2 = {1 : ["Moor", 22, 112, 60], 2 : ["Ling", 22, 114, 67]}
```

I did some digging but most solution given is - first column as key and second column as value.
This much I could think of, tried to split column by `readlines().split()[0]` but did not work.

```
f = open(fname)
d = {}
for line in f:
    name, info = line.split() 
    d[name] = info
print(d)
```

Any suggestion? Any Help? how should I do it? :)

Comment: Are you sure those are the dictionaries you want? There are alternative dictionaries that represent your data in more useful ways.

Comment: @pakpe That's what I was thinking too. For example maybe `{'John Moor': {'Age': 22, 'id': 112, 'grade': 60}, 'Amy Ling': {'Age': 22, 'id': 114, 'grade': 67}}`. Could also use `OrderedDict` if using Python 3.6- or if order is extra-important. Or maybe even better, use a Pandas DataFrame instead.

Comment: @pakpe yesss, actually this is just an example, I have large data to sort out this way. Thank you :). I could not thought of other ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**defaultdict**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to store data and **strip** and *split*** function to manipulate the line that you read.

**file.txt**

```
John  Moor
Age   22
id    112
grade 60

Amy  Ling
Age  22
id   114
grade 67
```

**Here is the Code:**

```py
from collections import defaultdict

dict1 = defaultdict(list)
dict2 = defaultdict(list)

with open("file.txt") as file:
    idx = 1
    for line in file.readlines():
        stripped_line = line.strip()
        if stripped_line:
            items = stripped_line.split(" ")
            dict1[idx].append(items[0])
            try:
                dict2[idx].append(int(items[-1]))
            except:
                dict2[idx].append(items[-1])
        else:
            idx += 1

print(f"dict1: {dict(dict1)}")
print(f"dict2: {dict(dict2)}")
```

**Output:**

```
dict1: {1: ['John', 'Age', 'id', 'grade'], 2: ['Amy', 'Age', 'id', 'grade']}
dict2: {1: ['Moor', 22, 112, 60], 2: ['Ling', 22, 114, 67]}
```

### Update

It would be more meaningful if you could store data like:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

dict1 = defaultdict(list)

with open("file.txt") as file:
    is_first_line = True
    key = None
    for line in file.readlines():
        stripped_line = line.strip()
        if stripped_line:
            items = stripped_line.split(" ")

            if is_first_line:
                key = items[0] + ' ' + items[-1]
            else:
                try:
                    dict1[key].append({items[0]: int(items[-1])})
                except:
                    dict1[key].append({items[0]: items[-1]})
            is_first_line = False
        else:
            is_first_line = True

print(f"dict1: {dict(dict1)}")
```

**output:**

```
dict1: {'John Moor': [{'Age': 22}, {'id': 112}, {'grade': 60}], 'Amy Ling': [{'Age': 22}, {'id': 114}, {'grade': 67}]}
```